# Get term from multiple taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I am trying to show all the terms from these taxonomies. However, I can't get them working. Please help, thanks

```
<?php 
$terms = get_terms(
    'taxonomy' => array(
        'category',
        'profile_status',
        'profile_skill')
);

if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_terms` is causing a parse error, you are missing the array part.

Also when using `get_terms` take into account that by default it will not return taxonomies that don't have posts attached to them.

The proper code would be like this

```php
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => [
        'category',
        'profile_status',
        'profile_skill'
    ]
]);
```

If you want to include empty taxonomies (taxonomies without posts attached to them), do this

```php
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => [
        'category',
        'profile_status',
        'profile_skill'
    ],
    'hide_empty' => false
]);
```